# Finding a complex functions real part

Tags: complex-analysis

Using the parameterization $C: z= 1 + e^{i\theta}$, theta between $0$ and $2\pi$, to derive $$Im \int_{C} \frac{Log(1+z)}{z-1}dz = \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \ln(5+4\cos\theta)d\theta$$

I'm not sure how to begin this. Any hints for it?

Comment: Of course you know how to start. How is a contour integral defined?

Comment: $\int_{\gamma} f(z) dz = \int_{a}^{b} f(z(t)) z'(t) dt$

Comment: So we have $z(t) = 1 + e^{it}, f(z) = (\log (1+z))/(z-1).$ What's the problem?

Comment: I suppose I'm not sure what to do with $\ln(2+e^{it})$

Comment: That should be $\log(2+e^{it}),$ right? How is $\log z$ defined (I assume you mean the principal value $\log$)